# How do i transform this image from having transparency to not having transparency?

Tags: textures, alpha, meshlab

i'd like to convert this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5IAo.png and remove the transparency of it to how it is visible in MeshLAb: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDQn9.png

why does this image show up like this in MeshLAb, and how do i save the image in Photoshop, or wherever, to result in it being shown like in mesh lab?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Meshlab is not removing the transparency of the image, but openGL (the graphics library used to render). This is due to the pixel format declared in the application.

Also, Meshlab is slightly changing the color due to shading, and merging with the color of the surface where the texture is mapped (a tone of grey)

Comment: thanks. it was just a matter of changing some settings on output in paintdotnet. newb here.  thanks again